# Dynamic key-based names of output files in new hadoop api

Tags: hadoop

Is it right that new hadoop api (there new - classes in package mapreduce, old - in package mapred) don't support output to key-named files? (without setting all this names at job configuration time)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems wrong to me. AFAIK `MultipleOutputs` from `mapreduce`can achieve the same behaviour than `MultipleOutputFormat` from `mapred`. See:

- Its [javadoc](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/output/MultipleOutputs.html) (search for `generateFileName`)
- This [blog post](http://grepalex.com/2013/07/16/multipleoutputs-part2/) from Alex Holmes. Alex's answer seems a bit more complex than required a simple use case since `public void write(KEYOUT key, VALUEOUT value, String baseOutputPath)` is available. But perhaps I am missing something.

Comment: At the end of blog post:

Comment: Hurray! We now have multiple output files that are dynamically created based on the reducer output key, just like we did with MultipleOutputFormat.

Now unfortunately the multi-named output is only supported by the old mapred API, whereas with the new mapreduce API you are forced to define your partitions in your job driver.

Comment: Conclusion

There are plenty of things to like about MultipleOutputs, namely its support for both “old” and “new” MapReduce API’s, and its support for multiple OutputFormat classes. Its only real downside is that multi named outputs are only supported in the old mapred API, so those looking for dynamic partitions in the new mapreduce API are not supported by either MultipleOutputs or

Comment: It looks like real bug in new api

Comment: Don't have time to write a proper test but I just read `MultipleOutputs` source code and I don't see why you could not use: `write(KEYOUT key, VALUEOUT value, String baseOutputPath)`. All it does is that it creates a new RecordWriter for each baseOutputPath using the OutputFormat of the job, as expected and as documented in the javadoc. Have you tried that ?